# Is there any verse to have nice husband?

Tags: mantras, men

Many of my friends married recently and all of them were either unhappy or divorced.

Can any one tell me any verses/slokas to get married to nice husband?

Comment: I seriously have no idea about WHAT exactly is being asked.

Comment: And why is it under 'mythology' tag :/

Comment: @WhisperingMonk, that post has answers only for finding a *nice wife*. Do we just replace the Sanskrit word for *wife* with *husband*? It's tagged `mythology` since a *nice husband*  is a mythical creature :-)

Comment: Artharva Veda has many of these. But you need to have the verses chanted by a competent brahmin versed in the Artharva Veda. If the verses are chanted with the wrong pronunciation, it can have the opposite result.

Answer (score 3):

### Gauri/Jaya Parvati Vrata to get husband like GOD Shiva

When observing Jaya Parvati vrat, one cannot eat tomato, salt, and vegetables. It is believed that Jaya Parvati vrat brings happiness and blesses the girl with a good husband and a happy married life.

An important Hindu ritual, Gauri Parvati Vrata is observed by unmarried women and young girls. Also known as Gouri Vrata or Gauri Vrat, this ritual is performed during the Hindu month of Ashadha and is dedicated to Goddess Parvati. Goddess Parvati is also referred to as Gauri. According to the Gregorian calendar, the date of this fast usually falls in the month of July or August. Gauri Parvati Vrat is immensely observed by the unmarried girls in the Indian state of Gujarat.

According to legends, Goddess Parvati had carried out intense austerities (tapas) in order to get Lord Shiva as her husband. Since then, unmarried females have been observing this fast on the pretext of obtaining an ideal and devoted husband, just like Lord Shiva. Gauri Parvati Vrat is observed for five days beginning on the Ekadashi day in the month of Ashada in the waxing phase of the moon. The fast ends on the day of Purnima. A partial fast is observed wherein the girls perform pujas for Goddess Parvati.

Jayaparvati Vrat katha or the story or legend of Jaya parvati vrat is associated with a Brahmin woman who observed this vrat to get her husband free from his curse(was not really a curse). The divine couple Lord Shiva and Goddess Parvati is worshipped during this Vrat.

There is a legend behind the Jaya Parvati Vrat. There was a Brahmin couple. They were devotees of Lord Shiva. They had everything in their life but a child. They used to worship Lord Shiva every day in the temple. Lord Shiva was propitiated with the devotion of the couple and there was a revelation which said ‘My Shiva Linga is at a certain place in the jungle. No body is performing its puja. If you go there and perform its puja, then your wishes will be fulfilled.’ The Brahmin couple was pleased when they heard this. They went to the jungle and found out the place where Lord Shiva’s Shiva Linga was. The couple found the Linga and the Brahmin went in search for flowers to perform the puja, where he was bitten by a snake and fell unconscious. His wife got worried as her husband did not return and went in search for him. She prayed intensely for her husband’s safety. Lord Shiva saw the true devotion of the Brahmin woman and brought her husband back to consciousness. Later, the couple prayed at the Linga and they were blessed with a son.

Answer (score 0):

For compatibility of marriages, Jatakam (translated as horoscope) matching is necessary, along with gotra and other physical compatibilities.
This must be done before a marriage takes place, obviously :)

Nowadays, people marry within gotra (sagotra marriage is similar to marrying brother or sister, but not that weird), or their parents did not bother to note the proper time of birth and the wrong janma-patrika (birth-chart) is calculated, or they don't care about all rules of jataka mathching..

Comment: Most posts on this website seem to discourage *matching physical compatibilities* before getting married. Is this actually encouraged in some scriptures?

Comment: Jyotisha shastra is as very much a part of Vedas. I don't know which post discourages it.

Comment: What does *physical compatibilities* refer to? @ram

Comment: @Jedi - usual stuff like height, weight, and basically they should be able to look at each other without being revolted :). If jatakas match but groom is 6'4" and 90kg, bride is 5'1" and 50kg, it could be bad for progeny.